# Cannot bind service from referenced library to another service

Tags: android, service, aidl

I am trying to bind a service from a library project that is added to another library project that is added to an application project.
So library A is referenced by library B and library B is added to my app. The app starts Service A. Another app starts Service B. Service B binds to service A but fails

```
ActivityManager(593): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.xx.yy.zz/.Service } U=0: not found
```

-I can find the jar containing the service in the application (in android dependencies).
-I declared the app in the manifest (application).

```
<service android:name="com.xx.yy.zz.Service"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">

</service>
```

-The service declaration is within the application tag.
-The service extends Service
-Both services produce Logs so they are both started

This is how I try to bind the service

```
private void bindToService() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Binding service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.xx.yy.zz", "com.xx.yy.zz.Service");
    mBound = getApplicationContext().bindService(intent, this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    Log.d(TAG, "bindService returned " + mBound);
}
```

mBound always returns false.
The services have been binded before (in a testapp which uses allot of the same code).
the services bind using AIDL (nothing changed to that code).

I cant paste more code so I hope this is enough to get me on the way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it, it turns out i had to provide the application package name and the library package name.

So instead of:

```
intent.setClassName("com.library.package.name", "com.library.package.name.Service");
```

I had to do:

```
intent.setClassName("com.application.package.name", "com.library.package.name.Service");
```

I hope this helps someone else! I wasted allot of time on this.

Comment: You could also create the Intent like this: Intent intent = new Intent(myActivity, TheService.class);